# Proof second derivative of inverse of a strictly concave function exists

Tags: calculus, inverse

Suppose I have functions $f,g$ which are strictly concave and strictly increasing. Also the first and second derivatives of $f$ and $g$ exist. This means that $f'(x)>0$ and $g'(x)>0$, and $f''(x)<0$ and $g''(x)<0$. I want to construct a function $h$ such that $g(x)=h(f(x))$.
Now I have to prove that $h''(x)$ exists and $h$ is an increasing function.

Furthermore I know that 
$$-\frac{g''(x)}{g'(x)}\geq -\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$$

I took $h(x)=g(f^{-1}(x))$. This is increasing since $h'(x)=g'(f^{-1}(x)) \cdot (f^{-1})'(x)$. Note that $f^{-1}(x)$ exists and because $f'(x)>0 \Rightarrow (f^{-1})'(y)>0$ and $g'(z) >0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}^+$.

I want to apply a similar method to show that the second derivative of $h$ exists, but I do not know how to show $(f^{-1})''(x)$ exists. I know that since the functions $f$ and $g$ are strictly concave we have that $f''(x)<0$ and $g''(x)<0$ but I do not see how this helps here.

Could you please help me?

Note: edit was to update question, I noticed I made a mistake in the formulation.

Comment: But $g^{-1}$ doesnt't have to be differentiable, so already your first proof doesn't work.

Comment: Are $f$ and $g$ given and do you want to prove hat $h = f\circ g$ has the said properties? Or do you want to find some $f$ and $g$ such that $h$ has the said properties? In general, a strictly concave function need not to be differentiable, let alone twice differentiable.

Comment: I should have also said that for both $f$ and $g$ their first and second derivatives exist.

Comment: I noticed I made a mistake, sorry for the unclear question. I hope it is better now.